# How to assign Javascript variable in html lang tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm looking for a way to assign the Javascript variable in one of html attribute.

```
<script>
     var code = callingSomeFunction(country);
     document.getElementById('lcode').lang = code;
</script>
<html id = "lcode" lang="[return value from code}">
```

It doesn't work here.  How can I get the value of the variable "code" outside the script for my lang attribute?

Comment: Why is your `<script>` above the `<html>` tag?

Comment: all HTML code should belong inside of the `<html>` tags to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured out once I added this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("lcode").lang = code;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just place the script-element before the closing body tag to ensure that the complete HTML is parsed and available as the DOM.